# How have they made new Foxy Bingo site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Foxy Bingo have just launched a new site `www.foxybingo.com` and it acts as a one pager, meaning you click on the main menu items and its scrolls down the page.

However when you click on a link the URL will change and not to the normal #anchor but instead bingo.html.

What else is interesting is if I visit `www.foxybingo.com/bingo.html` it will scroll down the to the correct part of the page on load but display a different meta title.

Edit:

How do I import multiple HTML files into one page like foxy does?

Comment: That's quite a broad question.

Comment: Read about History API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site don't include multiple pages but use [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) pushstate to change url with the name of the file like (using jQuery code):

```
var $win = $(window);
$('a#bar').click(function() {
    anim_jump($('#bar'));
    history.pushState(null, "page 2", "bar.html");
});

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  var file = document.location.replace(/.*\//, '');
  $('html, body').prop('scrollTop', $('#' + file.replace(/.html$/)).offset().top);
};
function anim_jump(item) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: item.offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```